# How to Properly match F# Class Type

Tags: f#

I'm working with C# object types, but I think the snippet below illustrates my problem.  I can't find anything related to the specific compiler warning, "This type test or downcast will always hold" (when matching against C# types I get "This rule will never be matched").
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937533/f-how-to-have-a-values-type-determined-by-a-match-statement) is similar, but seems specific to pattern matching (same results as below when using if/then/else).

```ml
type Parent =
  val a : int
  new(a0) = { a = a0; }

type Child(a) =
  inherit Parent(a)

let MatchFunc (obj:Parent) =
  match obj with
  | :? Parent -> "Parent"
  | :? Child -> "Child"
  | _ -> "Neither"

let c = new Child(1)
MatchFunc c
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`obj` is declared to be of type `Parent` so the first test will always match (and return). As such, the second case never will.

Match against the **most specific** types first, when types are related (in this case against `Child` first):

```
let MatchFunc (obj:Parent) =
  match obj with
  | :? Child -> "Child"  
  | :? Parent -> "Parent"
  | _ -> "Neither"
```

Note that the last case will never be hit if you handle explicitly all types in the hierarchy, however not having it would generate a rightful warning (as adding a new subclass of `Parent` would 'break' the pattern).

Comment: OK, nothing to do with F#; just confusing myself with simple OO hierarchy concept.

Comment: @dudeNumber4, well it has something to do with F#. A different language implementation could provide some 'magic' to always match against the most specific case :-) (I'm not saying that's desirable).